# Breezejs batch request with navigation property to OData

Tags: angularjs, odata, breeze

I am using breezejs + angular with olingo Odata v2 as backend service. I am able to get metadata correctly from Odata in breeze with Navigation Properties. However, when I tried to create an entity with association to other Entities. What breeze generates for me is something like {"displayName":"may 13","id":-1,"FK_page_id":1,"position":3,"FK_status_id":1,"title":"may13","weightPercentage":76,"FK_widget_id":1}
When I called manager.saveChanges(), it tried to create a batch request. Inside the batch request, it tried to post to the entity type and all those linked entities. I don't think this is correct behavior. How can I save just to the Entity type and also add relations to other entities?

Comment: It should be sending all added, changed, and deleted entities in the batch.  Is is sending unchanged entities?

Comment: It sends out the changes, but i think the link between entities is not correct. For example, I created an WidgetConfig Entity, it has relationship to Widget and Page. I don't need to post an new entity to Widget or Page, since the entities are already there. I just need to add the links to them. However, in the batch request, it post to WidgetConfig, Page, Widget separately.